# variable as object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use javascript variable in object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567278/use-javascript-variable-in-object-name)

I am using [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) as a rich text editor. I have dynamically generated textareas with a unique ID that need replacing with text editors. That is working fine, but I then need to call [getData();](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData) on the textarea to get the data for an AJAX call. This is easy enough:

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

The problem is I need editor1 to be dynamic, depending on the value of an attribute on a button. I record the textarea's identifier in a sibling button's name attribute:

```
var INSTANCE_NAME = $(this).attr('name');
```

Logging that out I get the correct editor ID back. (Note only using CAPS to highlight where it needs to be used in the next code block.)

I now need to use that `INSTANCE_NAME` as a variable like so:

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.INSTANCE_NAME.getData();
```

I imagine my entire code needs to look something like this:

```
var INSTANCE_NAME = $(this).attr('name');
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.INSTANCE_NAME.getData();
```

But I just get an error that `CKEDITOR.instances.INSTANCE_NAME` is undefined (which isn't surprising really)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to access properties in an object:

1. `object.property`
2. `object['property']`

Because the second option takes the property name as a string, you can build it dynamically — in this case, using the string `INSTANCE_NAME`:

```
var INSTANCE_NAME = $(this).attr('name');
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances[INSTANCE_NAME].getData();
//                                  \_____________/
//                                         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets:

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances[INSTANCE_NAME].getData();
```